# Word Addin: Is there a way to dynamically load the XML Manifest?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have a Word Add-in project running on my local server (e.g. `http://mylocal:1234/addin`) and a similar Word Add-in running on a remote server (e.g. `http://myremote.azurewebsites.net/addin`).

When I open from my local browser a Word document stored on the remote server, the Word Add-in loaded is my local's Add-in, but I would like to load the remote one.

So, I would like to load dynamically the Add-in situated in the same server of the document (whose location I could get from `Office.context.document.url`). Is there a way to achieve this behavior? I do not want to create different manifests.

This is my current Manifest's Source Location:

```
<DefaultSettings>
  <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Home.html" />
</DefaultSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be done. Any given manifest can have only one SourceLocation. You will need two manifests (with different `<ID>` values).

Answer (score 0):

One resolution: defvalue locate a html, you can do redirect in scipt element what you want dynamic url

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)